# Add dynamic style in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to copy existing styles from head and add it to window.open popup. below is my code

```
const styleElements = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

let printContents ='<html><head>';

forEach(styleElements, style => {
    printContents += style;
    console.log(printContents);
});
```

But I am getting:

```
[object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object
HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement]
[object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object
HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement]
[object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object
HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement]
[object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object
HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement]
[object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object
HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement]
[object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object
HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement][object HTMLStyleElement]
[object HTMLStyleElement]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

> The outerHTML attribute of the Element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can also be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

You are trying to concatenate string with object. 
Try [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) like the following way:

```js
const styleElements = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

let printContents ='<html><head>';

[...styleElements].forEach(style => {
  printContents += style.outerHTML;
  console.log(printContents);
});
```

```html
<style>.test{margin: 10px;}</style>
```

Comment: Very good suggestion as the OP had expected his script to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Updated:**

To copy styles to a new window opened via `window.open` you can try to copy just existent style objects to a document of the new window:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
var newHead = newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(styles, function(style) {
  newHead.appendChild(style);
});
```

You can review a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPdjrm

Comment: all css content displaying directly in page

Comment: does it include the tag name?

Comment: @user7789076 So instead of just showing all the styles do you want to apply all that styles to a window opened using `window.open`?

Comment: so then you need to create new style nodes and populate them with styles content

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below .

```
 forEach(styleElements, style => {
        printContents += style.textContent;
        console.log(printContents);
    });
```

Comment: all css content directly displaying in page

Comment: Style is an object in your code. try to use JSON.stringify(style) and check what it is returning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const styleElements = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

let printContents ='<html><head>';

Array.prototype.forEach.call(styleElements, style => {
  printContents += style.innerText;
});
console.log(printContents);
```

```html
<style>
.test{background-color:red;}
</style>
<style>
.test2{background-color:green;}
</style>
```